# More than one logfile for Glassfish?

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-4, java.util.logging

I'm running an application on GlassFish 4. I would like to have more than one logfile, so that I can log messages processed in MDBs(Message driven bean) into a special log file and not into the general Glassfish logfile. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Glassfish 4.0 Administration Guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf) Section 7 describes how to configure logging service.  For the root of your MDB logger namespace you have to turn off [Logger.setUseParentHandlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers-boolean-) to prevent writting to the default log. Then attach a [FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) or a com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler at the root of your MDB logger namespace to capture the output.  The [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) documentation describes how namespaces work.

Comment: I need to add a HK2 component for my custom logger, but I don't know how to do it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268183/writing-hk2-components-in-glassfish-4