# Writing HK2 components in GlassFish 4?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, hk2

In version 3 there is this guide on how to write components(including HK2 components):
Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Add-On Component Development Guide

This documentation is not available with GF4. Why not?

Why am I asking?

Because I want to write a custom Logging Handler, as documented in Chapter 7 of the administration guide(https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf).

"Note: The custom handler class should be packaged in an OSGi
module and the JAR file placed in the as-install/modules directory."

So how exactly do I proceed to create a HK2 component for GF4? Is it the same as GF3?

Comment: What type of handler are building?

Comment: @jmehrens http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish 4 added a new [handlerServices](https://java.net/jira/i#browse/GLASSFISH-19323) logging property that is not in GlassFish 3.  If your handler is a HK2 handler you have to place it in the modules directory and install the handler under the "handlerServices" property in the logging.properties file.  The [Hundred-Kilobyte Kernel](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0/) website contains all of the documentation to get you started.  I would reference the [GFFileHandler](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/4.1-b12/nucleus/core/logging/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/server/logging/GFFileHandler.java) source code and [Adding custom handlers to GlassFish v3 loggers](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/12/09/adding-custom-handlers-glassfish-v3-loggers) when building your handler.

The GlassFish 4 Administration Guide also states on page 7-17:

> To configure a custom handler that is not developed as an HK2 component, add the
>   new handler to the logging.properties file after the developer has put the custom
>   handler JAR file into the domain-dir/lib/ext directory

So you might be able to setup your handler without using HK2.  For these handlers you have to use the standard .handlers proprty in the logging properties file.

Comment: Im trying to create a Handler that is a subclass of GFFileHandler because I want it to have all the functionality of that one(filerotation, etc...). I don't think this will work in the /lib/ext directory because GFFileHandler is a HK2 component and has injected fields.

Comment: I found one change that was made in GF4 that changes how you install H2K handlers.  The answer has been updated.